# Embedding Matplotlib in PyQt5: Toolbar doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm developing an application for image-manipulation using matplotlib and pyqt5. Here's some code:

```
class MainForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("...", self)

        self.setup_ui_elements()

        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NaviToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        self.MiddleRightLayout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.MiddleRightLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)

    def plot(self, img):
        self.figure.figimage(img)
        self.canvas.draw()
```

Now if I load an image and plot it to the canvas, two problems arise:

1. The toolbar will be shown, but it has no effect (e.g. zoom, pan, etc.)
2. I haven't found a way to fit the image to the canvas, the image is usually much bigger as the canvas-area.

Any ideas?

greets, dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`figimage`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figimage.html) is directly placed onto the canvas without axes. This means it does not automatically scale to the canvas or anything else and it also means that the zoom and pan tools do not have any effect.

You may use the `resize` argument to figimage, `self.figure.figimage(img, resize=True)` to let the canvas fit to the image, if that is what you want. Otherwise, you'd probably want to use an `imshow` plot.

In order to get the image scaled to its original size, you need to work a bit on the spacings.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 


def plot(self, img):
    self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    self.figure.subplots_adjust(.1,.1,.9,.9) # 10% margin around image
    h, w = np.array(img.shape[:2])/self.figure.dpi
    self.figure.set_size_inches(w/0.8,h/0.8)
    self.ax.imshow(img)
    self.ax.axis("off") # in case you want to turn the axes off
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This is exactly what I want, the axes are not needed, but it also wouldn't be much of a problem if they are shown. I set the resize-argument to True but it still does not work. Maybe another idea what I did wrong? greets, dennis

Comment: *What*  does not work? `resize=True` fits the canvas to the image. Do you observe something different?

Comment: Ok sorry I misread your reply. The canvas size is indeed the size of the image if I set resize=True. So here's what I want to do: Showing the image in the center of the figure window, scaled to its size. And the toolbar should be working. So using imshow would be a better way to do that?

Comment: Yes, use `imshow` if you want a working toolbar. I updated the answer. (But I couldn't test it)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Edit: had to comment out line 3-5 to get it to work. I will look for the problem. Marked your answer as correct, cannot upvote you unfortunately.